# Oracle Apex changing a String of a object

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

So I want to get the Object which is essentialy a string. The issue is I cant transfer it into the string format since the resulting string is just anything but the thing I want. Bringing the object into a json doesnt bring a proper string either so my only way of achieving that is the concat method.
I have a Popup-Love which returns the string as follows foo, foo1 ,foo2 while I need it as
'foo1','foo2',...,'foo999' .
My method manages to do that for the first element while all the other elements remove the apostrophe resulting in something like 'foo,foo1,foo2'. How do i fix that?

```
var i = 0;
if(i == 0){
    var t ="'";
    var t = t.concat(apex.item("P29_STANDORT").getValue());
    var t = t.concat("'");
    apex.item("P29_TEST").setValue(t);
    i = i +1;
} else {
    var t = t.concat("'");
    var t = t.concat(apex.item("P29_STANDORT").getValue());
    var t = t.concat("'");
    apex.item("P29_TEST").setValue(t);
}
```

Comment: Which object are you trying to convert to a string? Is it your own JavaScript object?

Comment: The one which is beeing pulled from the item via the getValue() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can "overwrite" the native toString() function of the Object and replace it with a function that does what you want. Something like below

```js
function MyObj(){
  this.creationTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
}

MyObj.prototype.toString = function something(){
  return 'I was created on ' + this.creationTime;
}

var myObj = new MyObj();

console.log('String version of my custom object: ' + myObj);
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something but I just dont see how this will solve the issue. I cant use the methods which are related to toString() at all since the returning value doesnt make any sense. 
Even redefining the function wont change the fact that the string related functions such as replace/trim wont work on a object.

Comment: I suppose you post more code, including the getValue function that you are using so that we can understand exactly what you are trying to do and help you better.

Comment: The question is obsolet since the toString() functions seems to work just fine on the newer Version of Apex. Thanks for trying to help.